# Select elements which has certain descendent using Xpath

Tags: xpath

I want to Select all the LI elements which contain SPAN with id="liveDeal152_dealPrice" as descendents. How do i do this with xpath?

Here is a sample html

```
<ul>
    <li id="liveDeal_152">
        <p class="price">
            <em>|
                <span class="WebRupee">₹ </span>
                <span id="liveDeal152_dealPrice">495 </span>
        </p>
    </li>

    <li id="liveDeal_152">
        <p class="price">
            <em>|
                <span class="WebRupee">₹ </span>
                (price hidden)
        </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There are not `<LIST>` elements in your sample Xml.

Comment: i refered to li as list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//li[.//span[@id = 'liveDeal152_dealPrice']]` should do. Or more verbose but closer to your textual description `//li[descendant::span[@id = 'liveDeal152_dealPrice']]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
//li[.//span[@id="liveDeal152_dealPrice"]]
```

It selects

```
ALL <li> ELEMENTS
//li[                                    ]
     THAT HAVE A <span> DESCENDANT
     .//span[                           ]
             WITH id ATTRIBUTE EQUAL TO "liveDeal152_dealPrice"
             @id="liveDeal152_dealPrice"
```

That said, it doesn't seem like a very wise element selection, mostly due to the dynamically looking `id`. If you're going to use it once, it's probably ok, but if you're using it, say, for testing and will reuse it many times, it might cause trouble. Are you sure this won't change when you change your website and/or database?

---

As a side note:

- `ul` stands for "unordered list"
- `ol` stands for "ordered list"
- `li` stands for "list item"

Comment: sorry but i have to accept Martin's answer because he replied first

Comment: @user2443095 Goddamnit those 7 seconds!! No, just kidding, it's okay, we're glad we could help and let you learn something new today.