# php xpath find node with descendant having specific attribute

Tags: php, xpath

I have a multi level <ul><li> menu structure. I am trying to get the top level LI that has a descendant LI with a class of "current-menu-line".

My HTML

```
<ul id="menu1" class="nav">
  <li class="menu-item dorment-menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/index.html">welcome</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item dorment-menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/evidence.html">evidence</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item dorment-menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/network.html">network</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item dorment-menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/multi-page-pc-22.html">Multi page</a>
    <ul class="subnav">
      <li class="menu-item current-menu-line"><a href="http://localhost/new-page-1-pg-47.html">page 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried a number of xPath queries to get the topmost `<li>` that has the descendant with no success

```
$query = '//li[contains(@class, "current-menu-line")]'; // this one works ... makes sure LI.current-menu-line can be found
$query = '/ul/li[li[contains(@class, "current-menu-line")]]'; // returns 0 rows
$query = '/ul/li[//li[contains(@class, "current-menu-line")]]'; // returns 0 rows
$query = '/ul/li[descendant::li[contains(@class, "current-menu-line")]]'; // returns 0 rows
```

// added after examining "Select elements which has certain descendent using Xpath"

```
$query = '/ul/li[.//li[contains(@class, "current-menu-line")]]' ; // returns 0 nodes
$query = "/ul/li[descendant::li[@class, 'current-menu-line')]]"; // invalid query
```

Is someone able to tell me the correct query to get the correct LI ?

Cheers

Comment: simple hack, assuming that the target li is always two above the one with the class: `//li[contains(@class, 'current-menu-line')]/../..`

Comment: Good answer, unfortunately I cannot guarantee that the UL structure is only 2 deep

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select elements which has certain descendent using Xpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237312/select-elements-which-has-certain-descendent-using-xpath)

Comment: I looked there and tried the queries, they didn't work. See results in the edited question.

Comment: For others with the same problem, my loop solution was

    $query = '//li[contains(@class, "current-menu-line")]'; // returns 1 node
    $entries = $xpath->query($query);

    $entry = $entries->item(0) ;

    // we know that the parent of an LI is a UL
    while ( $entry->parentNode->hasAttribute('class') && ! preg_match('/\bnav\b/', $entry->parentNode->getAttribute('class')) )
    {
        // the while condition was not met so advance back up the tree to the previous LI
        $entry = $entry->parentNode->parentNode ;
     
    }

Sorry about the lack of formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This selection should fit your description:

```
 /ul/li[.//li[contains(@class, 'current-menu-line')]]
```

I see that you tried this already and it did not return any nodes for you, but I suspect there might be a difference in the XML-snipped that you provided to the actual XML that you use. I verified the XPath using [an online XPath evaluator](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi) and it returns the correct result even if the nested structure is more than two levels below.

Comment: Thanks for that tfoo. As you said, I had tried it and it hadn't worked. I copy/pasted directly from your suggestion but it still didn't work. This suggests it's a problem with PHP rather than DOMXpath.
The exact code I'm using is